# Include Threading in Flask with Uwsgi

Tags: flask, apache-kafka, uwsgi

I have a flask+uwsgi server in-place. I want to introduce a kakfa consumer within the same server, so that messages incoming in the kafka queue can use the APIs/objects present in the flask server. (Meaning, running flask APIs as well as consumer in the same python application). Upon looking, I found that we can create Threads in Flask, so I decided to create my Kafka consumer on a separate threads.

Here is a code to my main flask_app.py -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with flask_app.app_context():
        for ind, i in enumerate(range(4)):
            threading.Thread(target=create_and_start_kafka_consumer, daemon=True).start()

    flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7694, debug=False)
```

Here is my KafkaConsumer.py file -

```
def create_and_start_kafka_consumer():
    # Create a Kafka consumer instance
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'topic',
        bootstrap_servers=[<servers>],
        auto_offset_reset='latest',
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        group_id='<something>'
    )
    for message in consumer:
        ---logic----
```

Question :

1. Is this the right way to use Kafka in a flask+uwsgi setting?
2. If this is the correct setting, my 2nd question

--- 2nd Question ----
This app is running on my local when I run the flask_app.py directly, however, when I run it through uwsgi, the kafka consumer is not getting started up in the uwsgi worker processes. I have tried using **--lazy-apps** in *uwsgi.ini*, removing the master process, setting **--enable-threads** to true and using just **--lazy**. I want to know how can we enable support for threads despite setting all the values.

Here is my uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = flask_app.py:flask_app
master = true
processes = 1
threads = 10
enable-threads = true
stats = 0.0.0.0:7656
stats-http = true
enable-metrics=true
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
harakiri = 3000
auto-procname = true
thunder-lock = true
pidfile = flask_app.pid
;chdir =
;home =
;pythonpath =
;env =
;static-map =
max-requests = 50000000
max-requests-delta = 100
logfile-chown = true
disable-logging = false
threaded-logger = true
protocol = uwsgi
log-reopen = true
post-buffering = true
memory-report = true
single-interpreter = true
```

Here is the command I use to run my service :
`/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --lazy-apps`

I have been struggling with this for quite long now, I have gone through the forking mechanisms of uwsgi, but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than make threads in the code, you could simply set `processes = 4` in the config. Each *process* has a global interpreter lock (GIL). If you really wanted parallel processing for Kafka, plus its own async nature, you'd use asyncio with ASGI (Quart, Fastapi, etc), rather than Flask+uWSGI

Comment: The Flask service hosts an API, which updates some in-memory counts. If I set process more than 1, each process will have it's own memory, thus counts will be different, whereas I want the global counts.
I have tried using asyncio, but to no avail. Is there a working example which hosts an API + run the kafka consumer simultaneously. NOTE: The context for both API and kafka consumer should be same

Comment: Use a shared database like Redis to fix the count issue. Flask can run Kafka perfectly fine, as can an ASGI server with aiokafka, however, I'd recommend you deploy them as separate services, with Kafka writing to a database, and Flask reading it. Refer CQRS microservices pattern

Comment: Thanks for the insights.
- Flask can run Kafka perfectly fine
Can it run it alongside hosting an API server too? When I run a queue on a separate thread, and API server on the main thread, only 1 out of the 2 things work. Is it a problem in Flask, or I'm just implementing this wrongly. I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: The reason I want Kafka and Flask API server to run on the same process is : I don't want to implement backing off in Kafka client. Say my kafka client takes input from Kafka and tries calling Flask API which does some preprocessing before finally storing the data into DB. If Flask API and Kafka-client are 2 separate services, then my Kafka-client should backoff in case the Flask API is down (or else it will consume messages from Kafka but drop them). However, if I deploy them in the same process, if API is not there, this simply means, kafka client is also not there, leading to no extra check

Comment: Your Kafka Consumer should not block the HTTP server, which will happen when *synchonous* gateway interface (uWSGI). Therefore, Kafka should be a separate process or thread. Therefore, you should not *start* a consumer on any REST endpoint - it should be running upon "web-server process startup", in the background... Your Kafka consumer shouldn't call the Flask API; it should ideally compute results in-memory, then store in a persistent location that the API can then read using a database client, for example, and not rely on Kafka at all. In other words, do not couple the processes

Comment: Agreed!! Though not including a database in between was my whole point of introducing kafka, so that my Flask API doesn't have to store an index for querying the latest data (the queue will do this for me). I am now able to start a kafka consumer in the background, all the while not blocking the uWSGI server. The kafka process has the same memory access as the Flask API which I exactly what I wanted. If you have some spare time, I can share the boilerplate code with you and you can verify if it makes sense to do what I've done

Comment: Side question - When you mention that uWSGI is a synchonous gateway interface, does that mean I can't have 2 processes running on the same instance? In my case API server, and kafka consumer.

And huge thanks for the answer!!! Much appreciated.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer with your code... It's synchronous within one process, that operations will block. My answer told you to use 4 separate processes, which shouldn't conflict with one another... Then, if you had 4 or more partitions, for example, then the Kafka consumer group will be distributed amongst all of them and properly parallelize consumption to improve throughput... Kafka is not a replacement for a database if you need all those consumers to share information